# Roll up availability on AWS Elasticsearch Service?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-opendistro

Open Distro for Elasticsearch has [Rollup](https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/ism/index-rollups/) implemented. But this is missing on the AWS Elasticsearch service. I do really need this feature. Is there anyway to implement this feature or does anybody have any solution which they are currently doing in this area?

Comment: Which version are you running? i.e. what you get from `GET /`

Comment: version `7.7.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rollups were released in [version 1.12.0](https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/version-history/) of OpenDistro which includes version 7.10.0 of Elasticsearch OSS

Comment: Don't think that is out yet on AWS, I'll have to wait ) :

Comment: Hey maybe you can help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66254892/elasticsearch-snapshot-failing-in-aws-preventing-upgrade as well? Thanks heaps.